# how to communicate with angular component that is looped with *ngfor

Tags: angular

I have three components bookcomponent, pagecomponent and linecomponent. bookcomponent and linecomponent 
have grandchild/parent relationship. I can share data with service, which the linecomponent can subscribe 
but the problem is subscription written in the ngOnInit() method of linecomponent. linecomponent is looped
with *ngFor in pagecomponent because of which i am getting multiple subscription( subscription multiplied by
number of lines in the page)

@Input and @Output not possible because there is not direct relationship between component.

**bookcomponent.ts**

```js
export class BookComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private custStore: CustomerStoreService) { }
}
```

**bookcomponent.html**

```html
<page *ngFor="let cust of this.custStore.custs$|async [billcust]=cust></page>
```

**custstoreservice.ts**

```
readonly custs$ = this._custs.asObservable();
```

**pagecomponent.ts**

```js
selector: 'page',
template:`
  <span>{{billcust.name}}</span>
  <sub>{{billcust.mobile}}</sub>
  <line-figure [cust]=billcust "></line-figure>`

export class PageComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnChanges{
@Input()
  billcust: Object
}
```

**linecomponent.ts**

```js
selector: 'line-figure'

export class LineComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() cust: ICustomer;

  ngOnInit() {
    /*
    this.lineStoreService.ledgersumm$.subscribe(
      o=>{console.log(o)
        this.metric = o
      } //----->>> subscribe is multiplying with number of lines
    )*/

    if (this.cust.custid) {
      this.lineStoreService.ledgersummary(this.cust.custid)  
      // third party service to populate data for each line number
      .then(obj => {
        this.metric = obj;
        console.log(obj);
      });
    }
  }

  refresh(){
    this.ngOnInit()
  }
}
```

since linedata is updated based on the line number that comes from bookcomponent via pagecomponent there is no direct relationship. with the data so onchange hook can not be used

**update**

[image]

`BookComponent` is the host, which  instanciate `custstoreservice` 
(it is a state manager for cust array) in the constructor providing cust object as `@Input` to `PageComponent` (direct child of `BookComponent`).
`PageComponent` presents `cust.name` in the header thin blue-box in image and passes the `cust` object to its child `LineComponent` which then sets the `metric` object for this customer via `lineStoreService` in `LineComponent` pink-box in image.

Everything is fine till this point. Now i want the `LineComponent` to track data change for a `cust.id`. Have some buttons in the `LineComponent` that changes `metric` want a way to track this change.

I am able to update `metric` by clicking the refresh button in the `LineComponent` but this is manual. Want some automatic way.

I am free to change the approach, more concerned about the functionality any kind of example refrence will be helpful.

**linestoreservice.ts**

```js
export class LineStoreService  implements OnDestroy{

  constructor(private lineService: LineService) { }

  private readonly _ledgersumm = new BehaviorSubject<ILedgSummary>(null);
  readonly ledgersumm$ = this._ledgersumm.asObservable();

  get ledgersummC(): ILedgSummary {
    return this._ledgersumm.getValue();
  }

  set ledgersummC(val: ILedgSummary) {
    this._ledgersumm.next(val);
  }


  async ledgersummary(cid){
    this.ledgersummC = await this.lineService.ledgersummbydate(cid)
    return this.ledgersummC
  }

  async add(data){
     return await this.lineService.add(data).then(result=>{
       if(result){
        this.ledgersummary(data.custid)
       }
       return result
     }).catch(function (error) {
      console.error ("Oops: " + error);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: If each line component needs to request its own line independently, and you want to do this with Observables, the only way I can see of doing it is to have each component subscribe independently. If the page component is looping through lines with `*ngFor`, why can't you use `@Input`?

Comment: why not subscribe to lineStoreService.ledgersum$ in book component and pass as `@Input` the metric to pagecomponent? it's the susbcribe return an array you can pass `[metric]="response[i]"`

Comment: I tried adding ```lineStoreService.ledgersum$``` in the ```BookComponent``` constructor but setter expects custid as input. ```async ledgersummary(cid){
    this.ledgersummC = await this.lineService.ledgersummbydate(cid)
    return this.ledgersummC
  }``` added linestorageservice code

Comment: Just want to dispel one myth...@Input and @Output not possible because there is not direct relationship between component.....whilst it true you don’t want to do it too much you can keep passing / bubbling the event up and passing the input down. Fro example see the set an get methods for customer from following https://github.com/briebug/ngrx-complex-forms/blob/master/src/app/orders/components/order-form/order-form.component.ts

Comment: just to update, i was able to fix the issue by setting an action to update this.custStore.custs$ observable when the line is changes